# Почему нельзя единожды скомпилировать байт-код на конечной машине

Tags: java, компиляция, jvm, машинный-код

Что делает jvm? Учитывая все особенности среды в которой она работает (так как она именно под нее написана), интерпретирует байт-код, то есть динамически превращает в машинный код.

Так вот, почему нельзя единожды, при "установке" программы (то есть первом попадании) на компьютер с помощью jvm скомпилировать байт-код в машинный код и дальше уже *не* использовать jvm?

Ускорение ведь будет серьезное и может чуток памяти высвободится за счет *отсутствия* jvm. Ведь есть же JIT который делает то же самое, но во время выполнения программы и лишь кусками.

Comment: AOT есть для Android. Видимо, там считается достаточно полезным. Для остальных - надо спрашивать авторов JDK и JVM, а также дотнета, где то же самое (а .NET Native пока не везде и не для всего).

Answer (score 6):

> Так вот, почему нельзя единожды, при "установке" программы (то есть первом попадании) на компьютер с помощью jvm скомпилировать байт-код в машинный код и дальше уже не использовать jvm?

Потому что тогда нельзя будет использовать спекуляции, за счет которых JIT-скомпилированный код вполне легально может обгонять AOT-скомпилированный код. Например, у нас может быть метод со следующей сигнатурой:

```
void push(Consumer<Integer> consumer)
```

В этом случае АОТ ничего не останется кроме того, чтобы использовать интерфейс Consumer и вычислять реально вызываемый метод в рантайме. Однако если JIT на момент компиляции видит, что метод был вызван пять тысяч раз с одной и той же имплементацией Consumer - он может отбросить все лишнее, вызывать напрямую заранее известный метод и поставить перед этим т.н. trap на случай, если в метод все-таки упадет другая имплементация, и его надо будет перекомпилировать.

Также JIT позволяет эффективный инлайнинг кода, который также происходит на основе учета количества вызовов и размера метода. АОТ не может знать, какой участок будет горячим без помощи программиста (который, в свою очередь, может ошибаться), а JIT - вполне.

> Ведь есть же JIT который делает то же самое, но во время выполнения программы и лишь кусками.

JIT не делает этого кусками, весь код рано или поздно будет скомпилирован в машинный, просто пока компилятор не отработал, работает интерпретатор. Благодаря этому мы и можем, например, получить ассемблерный листинг.

Answer (score 1):

Небольшое не очень профессиональное объяснение работы исполнителей языка.

Существуют:

1. **Компиляторы**.
2. **Интерпретаторы**.
3. **И компилятора интерпретаторы, или интерпретаторы компилирующего Типа**.

Отбросим первые два, и обсудим третий.

Компилятор интепретирующего типа, это по сути компилятор и интерпретатор два в одном, поимер такого исполнителя это **JVM**, после написания текста программы, **JVM** в первую очередь использует компилятор, который компилирует ваш текст в байт-код, при этом этот этап имеет ряд оптимизаций, например пустые циклы, не проходят в байт-код, также бывает такое, что компилятор транслирует текст вообще в чистый машинный код, благодаря этому, достигается такая сумасшедшая скорость. Но следующим этапом, будет исполнения этого байт-кода, и вот этим, уже занимается JIT интерпретатор, которые интерпретирует машинный и байт коды, выводя нам результат.

Соответственно теперь вы сами должны понять, почему нельзя добиться единоразового исполнения — программа на половину, исполняется динамически, то есть, если байт код мы в принципе можем единожды скомпилировать, но интерпретировать байт-код нужно каждый раз уникально. Такая технология называется **JIT интерпретаторы**.

И-то все что я здесь описал, это без учета многих других моментов, оптимизаций, хаков и технологий... Но насколько мне известно, из любого приложения на `Java` Например, можно добиться итогового исполняемого файла, другой вопрос будет ли удобно каждый раз добиваться исполняемого файла и зачем вам тогда вообще язык на **JVM**? Ведь плюсы таких языков объективно видны на серверах, например.

Comment: Совершенно непонятно откуда следует, что "интерпретировать байт-код нужно каждый раз уникально". Просто из воздуха?

Comment: Ну так устроены интерпретаторы, думаете стоить поправить и пояснить как работает примитивный интерпретатор?

Comment: Так о том и вопрос - почему они так устроены. Почему нельзя за первый проход скомпилировать машинный код, а нужно каждый раз заново интерпретировать?

Comment: Интерпретаторы пусть будут устроены как хотят. ТС спрашивает, почему нельзя скомпилировать программу единожды на целевой системе. Иными словами зачем запускать JIT-компиляцию при **каждом запуске** программы, если ее можно запустить единожды и далее пользоваться готовым результатом?

Answer (score 1):

Для классов стандартной библиотеки это [уже делается](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295) начиная с Java 9. Есть мнение, что после всесторонней обкатки AOT-компилятор станет доступен и для пользовательских классов.

Comment: насколько понимаю, `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseJVMCICompiler` уже доступен

Answer (score -1):

> почему нельзя единожды, при "установке" программы (то есть первом попадании) на компьютер с помощью jvm скомпилировать байт-код в машинный код и дальше уже не использовать jvm?

Ответ очень простой, jvm - это программа которая уже скомпилирована в машинный код. jvm не может компилировать код вашей программы в машинный код при "установке" программы, так как не являтся компилятором.

В составе JDK имеется компилятор с языка Java, который компилирует в байткод. Байткод не является машинным кодом, поэтому может выполняться только на jvm.

Хотя, в природе были известны компиляторы с языка Java, такие как [gcj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java), но они почему-то не очень популярны.

Вот еще одна имплементация AOT, так называемая [GraalVM](http://www.graalvm.org/). Представялет из себя подмену JVM другой виртуальной машиной.

> #### [Компиляция AOT:](http://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/aot-compilation/)
>
> Полученная программа не запускается на виртуальной машине Java HotSpot, но использует необходимые компоненты, такие как управление памятью, планирование потоков из другой реализации виртуальной машины под названием «Субстратная виртуальная машина». Субстрат VM написан на Java и скомпилирован в собственный исполняемый файл.

Comment: В JVM (точнее, стандартном Hotspot) есть компиляторы C1 и C2 (плюс graal с непонятным статусом), которые компилируют байткод во вполне реальный машинный код.

Comment: Привели мне пример компилятора, который создаст мне exe-шник, который будет работать без JVM.

Comment: При чем тут экзешник? Но впрочем держите: http://www.graalvm.org/docs/examples/java-kotlin-aot/

Comment: Да, такой вот субстрат получается, ничего нового.

Comment: В смысле ничего нового? Считайте только что завезли.

Comment: Ничего нового, в смысле того что одну VM подменили на другую.

Comment: Это АОТ. Я сильно сомневаюсь, что там внутри есть классическая JVM.

Comment: Понятно что байткод там не выполняется, поэтому такую программу невозможно запускать в отдельной JVM.

Comment: [Что означает если ответ "принят"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)